# Replace a for loop with an Array map()

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.outputList.length; i++) {
  this.outputList[i].checked = this.selectedOutputs.includes(i);
}
```

Is it posssible to replace this with an array.map? I want to set the 'checked' property of items in the `outputList` to true if it's index exists in the `selectedOutputs` array. I can't wrap my head around how this would look using a map function.

Comment: Not sensibly. I avoid indexed `for` loops whenever I can, but I think what you're doing currently is just fine.

Comment: map returns an array and i don't think that's what you are looking for

Comment: `.map` is when you want a *new* array based on a previous one. Since it doesn't seem you're iterating one array and producing another from it, then `.map` is *not* a good choice.

Comment: You can use `forEach` for this. But map isn't a good match

Comment: @SifatHaque Thanks, would I have to use an indexer with a `foreach`? Could you show me how that would work?

Comment: @noclist please check my reply. I've shared the `forEach` implementation there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i think `forEach` is a good match for your purpose. Here you can check the same implementation using `forEach`.

```
  this.outputList.forEach((outputList, i) => {
    outputList.checked = this.selectedOutputs.includes(i);
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

No, since you are trying to mutate the objects in the `outputList` instead of building a completely new list, you *should not* use `map`. If you just don't like `for (let i=0; i<length; i++)` loops, you can use `for … of`:

```
for (const [i, output] of this.outputList.entries()) {
  output.checked = this.selectedOutputs.includes(i);
}
```

However, depending on the structure of your `selectedOutputs` array and assuming that `.checked` was initialised with `false` for every output, there might be an even better (and more efficient) approach:

```
for (const i of this.selectedOutputs) {
  this.outputList[i].checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
this.outputList = this.outputList.map((item, i) => ({
  ...item,
  checked: this.selectedOutputs.includes(i),
}));
```

This will create a new array object from the old array, so it doesn't do the exact same thing. As others mentioned, it's best to use a `for` iteration in case you shouldn't create a new array object.